# How to Merge Updates to Auto Generated Hibernate POJOs?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on a Hibernate-based project using annotation configured Hibernate POJOs.  The original Hibernate-generated POJOs were modified include non-Hibernate methods and custom types (e.g. enums).

When updating the data model what is the best way to efficiently merge the changes to the hibernate-generated portion of the objects?

Comment: What is hibernate-generated here?

Comment: @user714965 The POJOs were originally auto-generated from the database using the standard hibernate utilities.

Comment: So it appears that diff is the current best practices.